# Is it possible to load docstrings for a class from a different file in PHP (PhpStorm/IntelliJ)?

Tags: php, laravel, intellij-idea, phpstorm

In my Laravel application I created a script that exports the attributes of my model classes to TypeScript interfaces. Thanks to those interfaces, my IDE knows which attributes the TypeScript objects should have.

Now, I'd like to go a step further and have my IDE also know about the attributes for each PHP class. For this, I'd like to create PHP Docstring definitions in separate files and link them to the actual class file. The linking would be okay to set manually.

My directory structure would look like this:

```
/classes/MyModel.php
/definitions/MyModel.php
```

The definition file for the class should only contain the Docstrings for the class:

```
// file: /definitions/MyModel.php
/**
 * @var string $myStringAttribute
 */
```

Now, I'd like to include this generated file somehow in the class MyModel, so any IDE can know which attributes the Model can access from the DB. I already tried including the definitions file with `include __DIR__ . '/../definitions/MyClass.php'` but this did not work.

Outputting the Docstring definitions in the actual class file is not really an option for me. With separate files, I would just need to add a single line of code to the classes to link the definitions.

Is there a way of doing this that could work? Or maybe there are plugins for my IDE (PhpStorm/IntelliJ) which could do this (official Laravel Plugin did not do this)?

This is a quality-of-life question. I know I could write the docstrings for each class myself, but I prefer to have them generated automatically to be on par with the actual model definition in the database without manual work.

Comment: TL;DR: some time ago I used reflections to read PhpDoc, quite possible that you can make some usage of it. Sorry no access to this code now, so can't give you any sample right now.

Comment: Yes and No at the same time. PHP and PhpStorm do not have "definitions" thingy that TypeScript has (`*.d.ts` files). Look at what Laravel IDE Helper package does for ordinary Laravel classes: it creates a small "copy" of the class and adds all the magic/dynamic methods there so the IDE can follow and recognize them. Downside: IDE will show "duplicate class definition" and will highlight it as a Weak Warning (that inspection can be disabled though).

Comment: Other possible alternative: try another Laravel plugin, e.g. **Laravel Idea plugin** is a paid one, is in active development ... but offers MUCH more than original old **Laravel plugin** (which AFAIK rarely sees updates nowadays). Give it a go (trial) and see how it can help you here. IMO if you are using Laravel a lot it well worth the money spent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I also saw duplicate classes in someones code but did not like this approach. Just hoped i could utilize docstrings. I will have a look at the plugin